# Google calendar: Show availability without revealing personal calendar details to admin

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar

- I have a "work" Google Calendar and several "personal" Google Calendars

  - The work calendar is administered by my company
- **I'd like to show coworkers my combined availability (work *and* personal)**, but hide the personal event details

  - I can't share my personal calendar with the setting "Make changes *and* manage sharing" because I don't want the admin to have full read/write access to it)

**Is there a way to do this within Google Calendars?**

Zapier allows me to automatically mirror new personal calendar events onto my work calendar, but this is expensive and inelegant. I'm hoping someone here knows a better way.

Answer (score 3):

When I go into **Calendar settings** → **Share this Calendar** I get the following *Permission Settings* for sharing my calendar with any given individual:

[image: Calendar Permission Settings]

Answer (score 0):

With G Suite (your work account) have your admin update the sharing settings so that people outside your domain can access details of your work calendar.

[image: Calendar Sharing G Suite admin panel]

Then after 24 hours or so you should be able to "share" your work calendar with yourself (personal Gmail or G Suite).

Just like the answer from user13779. Just pick the option that works best for you and your employer.

[image: Calendar Permission Settings]

My 2¢.

Different companies have different security protocols and policies.

All the best @FlightPlan!