# Create shared Google calendar, sharing everyone's events without showing details

Tags: google-calendar

I want to create a shared calendar with a group of friends, showing everyone's availability, without everyone having to go out of their way to create a detail-less copy of all their personal events to share.

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/97839/google-calendar-show-availability-without-revealing-personal-calendar-details-t) is close to what I want, in that any one of us can share availability-only with another account, but if I understand correctly, only that account owner (ie, the "given individual" in the upvoted answer to that question) would be able to see all the shared events together. What I would like to be able to do is:

- Create an account and give it a calendar
- Have everyone simply share their events at free/busy detail level with that account as per the answer to the linked question, meaning they don't have to create duplicates of everything they add
- Said account can now see everyone's availability
- Have that account share its calendar with my friends and myself
- Everyone can now see everyone else's availability

Would that 4th/5th step work? Or is everyone just going to have to create a detail-less duplicate of each event to add to a shared calendar?

I'll be testing this myself, but thought it could be a useful question to ask in the meantime.

Comment: You don't share events you share calendars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and as far as I understand what you are after I think your approach (whilst perfectly sensible) won't achieve what (I grasp of) your goal.

If you all individually share a calendar with a *"central"* account, said account will be able to see your individual unavailabilities but not *forward them* in turn.

Best option (for that specific problem, ignoring all pootential problems that this would bring along) would be to have a common account, shared by everyone that they sync there devices to and that they share their calendar with ...

That is less than ideal but that is the best I have to offer.

Maybe you can look for a way for every one to share with a list of a group but I'm not sure about that.

(and just a word of warning, I've had an experience of this where multiple people shared unavailabilities like this but all-day events never showed up. It took us way too long to realise that those are set to `availability:free` by default ...)